# jquery dynamic content generated by dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
(function(){ 
    if (typeof $(".grid") === "undefined") {
        return false;
    } else {
        var count = 0;
        var images_to_place_container = ".grid";
        for (var image in images_to_place) {
            $(images_to_place_container).prepend("<div class = grid-item><div class=grid-item-hover></div><a href=work.php><img src=" + images_to_place[count] + "></a></div>");
            count++;
        }
     }
})();
```

I have this code that is dynamically generating images for a site, now what I want is that when I hover over one of these elements, I want to dynamically generate a div that is the same size and in the same position as the dynamically generated object I hovered over . Also, all elements are absolutely positioned using CSS. Thanks.

Comment: `$` method of `jQuery` always returns an `object` and `object` is never a `falsey` value..

Comment: If you want to check that matching elements do not exist, use `$(".grid").length === 0` or simply `!$(".grid").length`.

Comment: oh what should I say instead of return false? (even though the code works, any tips on the question ?)

Comment: Read about [__`jQuery.clone()`__](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div class='container'>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //this dynamically "creates" the images...
    $(".container").append("<img src='something.png' class='abc'>");

    //this watches for click triggers on dynamically created elements
    $(".container").on("click", "img.abc", function(){
        var pos_top = $(this).css("top");
        var pos_left = $(this).css("left");
        var obj = "<div class='def'></div>";
        $(obj).css("top", pos_top);
        $(obJ).css("left", pos_left);
        $(".container").append(obj);
    });
});
</script>
```

Give classes `abc` and `def` the necessary css rules such as position, margin etc.